# Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView runtime error

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView` in a brand new WPF app with the latest NuGet package. Installed the latest version on Windows 10.

I am seeing this error:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture.  Make sure
>   "Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.DesignerUI.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.DesignerUI.resources is a resource file within  the Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView nuget package .

Comment: what version of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: vs 2017 enterprise edition . Also I did the same in VS 2017 community edition in my home laptop , and I am not able to see this issue , very strange .

Comment: I seem to get this error when I have a value specified for IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled

If I remove the line of code in the designer which sets this, the error goes away